# Mapping DAO transactions

Tags: thedao-refund

I was reconciling my old transactions to my current total in etherscan.io and noticed that ETH 2.75 that I had sent in May 2016 to the DAO were never credited back. I downloaded a file named TheDAOETCRefundAccountOutstandingBalance into Excel, and found out that there is one entry with my wallet address, which under the column Hardfork Balance has 2.115 and under the column Current balance has 1.547. If I go to refunds.thedao.fund and enter my wallet account number I see zero everywhere, so I'm stomped and perplexed as to where my initial ETH 2.75 went, how to reconcile that with the numbers found in DAO ETC Refund file, and why everything is zero in refunds.thedao.fund. I really would like to recover that money.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer at https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/The_DAO_Refunds#How_Do_I_Check_If_My_Account_Has_Any_Remaining_The_DAO_Refund_Due

Interesting to note that at the **DAO to ETH refund** I found about 77% of it, and in the **DAO To ETH ExtraBalance Refund** the balance. The proportion between the two is such that for every Ξ1 (ETH) in the former there are exactly    Ξ0.30 in the latter.